# Spring batch commit interval for CompositeItemWriter

Tags: transactions, spring-batch, commit, compositeitemwriter

How does spring batch identify the commit `interval` in a `compositeItemWriter`?

If my `commit-interval=50000`, and I have a `CompositeItemWriter`, which has 4 different writers included, each of which is passed a list of `50000` records.
Is the transaction committed at the end of writing 200000 ( `50000 * 4`) records ?

If 1 of the `itemWriters` fails due to an `exception`, what happens to the entire `transaction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CompositeItemWriter` will write 50k objects. Therefore each delegate writer will write 50k objects, resulting in 200k total writes in your case.

The question of Transaction management is hugely complex, but in an ideal world, all 4 writers will roll back so you can restart at the beginning of the chunk that failed